# Close notification drawer in android 12 CRASH

Tags: java, android, kotlin, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to open a activity in broadcast receiver but the notification drawer's not closing.
as ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS is deprecated the app is crashing, is there any other solution for this?

```
nLServiceReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        println("BroadcastReceiver----${intent.action}---------------/--/-/-/-/-/-/-/-")
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            currentAppActivityList.clear()
            if(SDK_INT < 31){
                val closeIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS)
                applicationContext.sendBroadcast(closeIntent)
            }
                      startActivity(applicationContext.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("${intent.action}"))
        }, 1000)

    }
}
```

on notification there are different buttons (dynamic), every button defines a different app. so if i tap on the button, it should open its assigned application.

ive tried providing below in the pending intent

```
val intent1 = Intent(context.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(appInfo!![i].packageName))
val pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
```

but wanted to do some operations before application launch, so i added broadcast reciever.

```
val pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, Intent(appInfo!![i].packageName), PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
```

its working fine but notification drawer is not closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

question is about crash, where is it? don't you think that this is crucial for solving your issue? put some log, exception stacktrace...

but I know what `Exception` you are getting: `SecurityException`. Thats because you are using [ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS) and straight in doc you can find:

> This constant was deprecated in API level 31.

> This intent is deprecated for third-party applications starting from Android Build.VERSION_CODES#S for security reasons. Unauthorized usage by applications will result in the broadcast intent being dropped for apps targeting API level less than Build.VERSION_CODES#S and in a SecurityException for apps targeting SDK level Build.VERSION_CODES#S or higher. Instrumentation initiated from the shell (eg. tests) is still able to use the intent. The platform will automatically collapse the proper system dialogs in the proper use-cases. For all others, the user is the one in control of closing dialogs.

so:

- now only user or system can close notification drawer
- always read/post exception stacktrace
- read the doc

Comment: is there any other way to perform this kind of operation?

Comment: afaik this behavior (no-op `Intent`) was introduced because of "security reasons", so there is no option left. And even when there is still such possibility in any other hacky way - it's a bug against current security policy and probably already is in newest OS version or at least will/should be fixed in future release